# Don't work "show all" filter

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have products sorted by categories and I want to do pagination for products of every category and button "show all" that show all products in chosen category. 
**But when I click "Show all" I get products from first category.**

*product/views.py*

```
class CategoryView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'shop/product/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'category_slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'])
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.active()
        context['products'] = Product.objects.active(category=context['category'])
        context['brands'] = Brand.objects.filter(product__in=context['products']).distinct()
        context['weight'] = filter(None, sorted(list(set(list(p.weight if p.weight is not None else None for p in
                                                              context['products'])))))
        context['package_type'] = filter(None, sorted(list(set(list(p.package_type if p.package_type is not None else
                                                                    None for p in context['products'])))))
        context['color_type'] = filter(None, sorted(list(set(list(p.color_type if p.color_type is not None else None
                                                                  for p in context['products'])))))
        product_filter = {}
        context['product_filter'] = product_filter

        if 'filter' in self.request.resolver_match.kwargs:
            filters = self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['filter'].split(";")
            for f in filters:
                if "brand_" in f:
                    product_filter['brand'] = [x for x in f.split("brand_")[1].split(',')]
                    context['products'] = context['products'].filter(brand__slug__in=product_filter['brand'])
                if "weight" in f:
                    product_filter['weight'] = [str(x) for x in f.split("weight_")[1].split(',')]
                    context['products'] = context['products'].filter(weight__in=product_filter['weight'])
                if "package_type" in f:
                    product_filter['package_type'] = [str(x) for x in f.split("package_type_")[1].split(',')]
                    context['products'] = context['products'].filter(package_type__in=product_filter['package_type'])
                if "color_type" in f:
                    product_filter['color_type'] = [str(x) for x in f.split("color_type_")[1].split(',')]
                    context['products'] = context['products'].filter(color_type__in=product_filter['color_type'])

        show_all_products = self.request.GET.get('show')
        if show_all_products == 'all':
            products = Product.objects.active(category__id=context['categories'])
            print (context['categories'])
        else:
            paginate = 3
            products_per_page = getattr(settings, 'PRODUCTS_IN_CATEGORY_PER_PAGE', paginate)
            paginator = Paginator(context['products'], products_per_page)
            page = self.request.GET.get('page')
            try:
                products = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                products = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['products'] = products
        return context
```

*category.html*

```
{% if products.paginator %}
        <div class="pagin">
            <a href={% url "shop_product_category_view" category_slug=category.slug  %}?show=all   class="all">{% trans 'Показать все' %}</a>
            {% if products.has_previous %}

                <a href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}" class="nav_buttons">
                    <span class="icon icon-necessary_to_know-nav-left"></span>
                    {% trans 'Пред' %}
                </a>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you show the `.active` ModelManger?

Comment: Ditch this code! Sorting is done at the database level. Not by retrieving the whole table and doing it in django. Filtering is also done at the backend. learn about django relations. Better still start by learning about database relations.

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada  `class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(active=True, **kwargs).order_by('sort_order')
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the code below did not throw an error

```
products = Product.objects.active(category__id=context['categories'])
```

But I assume that to achieve what you want you should change the return of `context['products']` to a list and change your queryset from `__id` to `__in` and like

```
products = Product.objects.active(category__in=context['categories'].values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant took the right category.

I just write `Product.objects.active(category=context['category'])` instead `products = 
Product.objects.active(category__id=context['categories'])`

```
 show_all_products = self.request.GET.get('show')
    if show_all_products == 'all':
        products = Product.objects.active(category=context['category'])
```